# mapping from flat protobuf message to class with inner classes using mapStruct

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, mapstruct

I need to use `mapStruct` to write a mapping from message `AddressProto` to the `class` Address. But message `AddressProto` consists only of string fields while `Address` class has inner classes.

I have written such a mapper so far, but due to the difference between the message structure and the class, I don’t know how to correctly map fields from message `AddressProto` to class `Address` and back.

```
@Mapper(config = MapstructConfig.class, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public abstract class AddressProtoMapper {

  // from proto to object
  public abstract Address mapToAddress(AddressProto address);

  // from object to proto
  public abstract AddressProto mapAddressToProto(Address address);
}
```

proto message `AddressProto` (after the slash for each field, I wrote in which class field it needs to be mapped):

```
message AddressProto {
    string value = 1;               // Address.AddressValue.value
    string unrestricted_value = 2;  // Address.AddressValue.unrestrictedValue
    string country = 3;             // Address.Structure.Country.name
    string country_iso_code = 4;    // Address.Structure.Country.isoCode
    string region = 5;              // Address.Structure.Region.name
}
```

java class `Address`:

```java
public class Address {
    public final AddressValue value;
    public final Structure structure;


    public static class AddressValue {
        public final String value;
        public final String unrestrictedValue;
    }


    public static class Structure {
        public final Country country;
        public final Region region;

        public static class Country {
            public final String name;
            public final String isoCode;
        }

        public static class Region {
            public final String name;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple. Even too much :)
You just need to write your own implementation.

```
@Mapper(
    config = MapstructConfig.class,
    unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR
)
public interface AddressProtoMapper {
  default Address mapToAddress(AddressProto address){
    return new Address(
        ...
    );
  }

  default AddressProto mapAddressToProto(Address address) {
    return new AddressProto(
        ...
    );
  }
}
```